# Find a matrix P such that $P^{-1}AP=J$, where $J$ is in Jordan normal form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$A=\begin{pmatrix} -6 & 0 & 1 & -5 \\ 5 & - 1 & -1 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 5 & 0 & -1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$

I found the Jordan normal form to be

$J=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 &0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$.

I know next that I have to solve $(A+1)v_2=v_1$ to find $v_1= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1\\0\\-1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, where you can then go on to find two more vectors, but I dont understand why this proccess works, can someone explain? Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the proof of the Jordan canonical form you know, this falls right out. I recommend Artin's algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's follow the algorithm described [here](http://math.rice.edu/~friedl/math355_fall04/Jordan.pdf).

It seems that you have found that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
\chi_A(t)=(t+1)^4
$$
so the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda=-1$ with algebraic multiplicity $m=4$. Note that
\begin{align*}
A+I &= \left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
-5 & 0 & 1 & -5 \\
5 & 0 & -1 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
5 & 0 & -1 & 5
\end{array}\right]
&
(A+I)^2
&=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\dim\operatorname{Null}(A+I) &= 3 & \dim\operatorname{Null}((A+I)^2) &= 4
\end{align*}
we then compute the numbers
\begin{align*}
d_1 &= \dim\operatorname{Null}(A+I) & d_2 &= \dim\operatorname{Null}((A+I)^2)-\dim\operatorname{Null}(A+I) \\
&= 3 & &= 4-3 \\
& & &=1
\end{align*}
so we must fill the boxes
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\Box & \Box & \Box \\
\Box
\end{array}
$$
with vectors. Note that $e_1=\langle1, 0, 0, 0\rangle$ satisfies $e_1\in\operatorname{Null}((A+I)^2)$ but $e_1\notin\operatorname{Null}(A+I)$. Put 
$$
v=(A+I)e_1=\left\langle-5,\,5,\,0,\,5\right\rangle
$$
so the diagram takes the form
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
v & \Box & \Box \\
e_1
\end{array}
$$
Since $w=\left\langle1,\,0,\,0,\,-1\right\rangle$ and $x=\left\langle0,\,0,\,5,\,1\right\rangle$ are two linearly independent vectors in $\operatorname{Null}(A+I)$ that yield a basis $\{v, w, x\}$ of $\operatorname{Null}(A+I)$ we may complete our diagram with
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
v & w & x \\
e_1
\end{array}
$$
This gives $A=PJP^{-1}$ where
$$
P = \left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
-5 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
5 & 0 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$